# Can a sequence of json objects be unequivocally parsed without further delimiters or knowing their length?

Tags: json, api, sockets, distributed

I am planning a protocol where two applications open a socket between them and send and receive legal json objects.

Can a sequence of json objects be unequivocally parsed, or will I need delimiters, or prefixing each object with its lengths or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real JSON objects always start and end with matching { and } characters. So you should be able to build a stream parser that correctly determines the boundaries on the fly, without needing to know the lengths in advance.

See [json.org](http://www.json.org) for details of the syntax.

Comment: True. Additionally legal JSON values also include arrays, which are enclosed in [ ] (legal json values are Objects and Arrays).

Answer (score 0):

Valid JSON objects have balanced delimiters.

Can you be 100% sure that you will only receive valid objects? Can you have network glitches? What about if the sender dies in mid transmission? I think you'll need either:

a). Some agreement about the JSON objects you're receiving so that you can ignore a partial stream until you see the start of one of your agreed payloads. Eg. everything is an  "Envelope" object

b). a stack-like recovery mechanims pushing and "popping" counting opening and closing delimiters until you are sure you have the beginning of  a new record. With sufficiently pathalogical corruption this sounds hard to do reliably.

I very much prefer the first option.